# Maven shade copy WEB-INF

Tags: java, maven, maven-shade-plugin

Using **maven-shade-plugin** I am trying to create a project file structure as follows:

[image]

The problem is that the following pom configuration is not creating the WEB-INF directory.

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <filters>
                            <filter>
                                <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                                <excludes>
                                    <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                                    <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                                    <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                                </excludes>
                            </filter>
                        </filters>
                        <createDependencyReducedPom>true</createDependencyReducedPom>
                        <transformers>
                            <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                <mainClass>com.my.package.Main</mainClass>
                            </transformer>
                        </transformers>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Basically I need to copy my web.xml file, classes and lib files into a directory called WEB-INF in the root of the project.

**Update:** SORRY, I copied the wrong plugin from my pom into the original question!

**Update:** If I add the packaging from the pom declaration: `<packaging>war</packaging>` The WEB-INF file structure is completed as per the OQ. However, with this declaration the `com` directory now does not contain my packages so the main class cannot be found.

How it looks with the `<packaging>war</packaging>`:

[image]

How it should look:

[image]

Comment: Sounds like you try to create a WAR archive, why not using maven-war-plugin for that purpose?

Comment: I tried the maven-war-plugin. I am trying to create an executable war with a main class. However, the main class CANNOT be in the default package. It MUST be in a declared package.

Answer (score 0):

[maven-assembly](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/) plugin allows much more flexibility, it would be easily accomplished by using assembly plugin

---

**See**

- [assembly descriptor examples](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/advanced-descriptor-topics.html)

Comment: Im not familiar with maven-assembly-plugin. Don't seem to be having much luck with it.

Comment: its assembly descriptor is pretty straight forward you specify input directory and output directory inside assembly it assembles it for you, checkout some examples

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of possible answer to achieve the desired effect with maven. However, based on the update I gave I found that adding the **maven-antrun-plugin** with the following solved my issue:

```
<plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>move-main-class</id>
                    <phase>compile</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <tasks>
                            <copy todir="${project.build.directory}/${project.artifactId}">
                                <fileset dir="${project.build.directory}/classes/">
                                </fileset>
                            </copy>
                        </tasks>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>run</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```